Splitting audio m4b file into separate files based on a cue file
Splitting audio m4b file into separate files based on a cue file
How can I split an audio m4b into separate files using a cue file?
Note: The m4b file has no chapters that's why I need to use the cue file to split it.
I did try AI but that didn't work.
ffmpeg -i test.m4b -f segment -segment_times test.cue -c copy output_%02d.m4a

I get errors.

Invalid time duration specification 'test.cue' in times list test.cue
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
?): Invalid argument

The thing is I can load the cue file in vlc and play the different chapters without issues.

Maybe you can use flacon to split the file? Otherwise convert it to a flac file and then use flacon?
